# How to declare a var with a customized name in js?

Tags: javascript, variables

I would like to declare a variable whose name is the content of another other variable. It is possible ?

I tried this :

`var "x" + "y" = 1;`

to declare this :

`var xy = 1;`

But this throw an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: `window['x'+'y'] = 1;console.log(xy)`

Comment: And then how would you access them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way (AFAIK) to create local variables with dynamic names is with `eval()`. This is not a great solution, because of performance concerns. You can also create global variables with dynamic names using the global object.

```js
eval(`var ${varName} = 123;`);
globalThis[varName] = 123;
```

However, creating variables with dynamic names is not a common practice. Most likely what you need is a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
const varName = "varName", otherVarName = "otherVarName";

const map = new Map();
map.set(varName, 123);
map.set(otherVarName, 456);
console.log(map.get(varName), map.get(otherVarName));
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript somehow you can create dynamic variables using eval function or window object:

```js
eval('var xy="evalTest";');
alert(xy);
window["xy"] = "windowTest";
alert(window["xy"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to create a json with all your global variables.

```
//create an empty json (at the top of your javascript file)
const globalVariables = {}; 

//add variable and value to your json
globalVariables["x"+"y"] = 1; 

//access value from json
console.log(globalVariables["xy"]); // this function will log 1 to the console
```